# How do I know how many hours it took an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/191/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<input class="Time1" value="10:00" />
<input class="Time2" value="10:30" />
<input class="Hours" value="0" />
<hr>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$(function () {
    function calculate() {
        var hours = parseInt($(".Time2").val().split(':')[0], 10) - parseInt($(".Time1").val().split(':')[0], 10);
        if(hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
        $(".Hours").val(hours);
    }
    $(".Time1,.Time2").change(calculate);
    calculate();
});
```

Moments of input values are:

1.`Time1=10:00;`

2.`Time2=10:30;`

the result would be of the form

```
00:30
```

currently is calculated and the result

```
is 0
```

If the exchange values of the respective input with `2:00 p.m. 4:00 p.m.` the result will be `2` and should be of the form  `02:00`

How can we fix these bugs?
Can you help me find a solution please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you ever tried using function in JS like Date().get Time()?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a library such as Moment.js (and you shouldn't, for a trivial task like this), then it's best to use JavaScript's native date functionality:

```js
function recalculate() {
  // Come up with a couple dummy dates with the given times:
  var d1 = new Date("2000-01-01T" + document.getElementById("Time1").value);
  var d2 = new Date("2000-01-01T" + document.getElementById("Time2").value);
  // Calculate their difference in milliseconds
  var msecDifference = (d2 - d1);
  // If it's less than zero, add 24 hours to it (since we're spanning days)
  if (msecDifference < 0) msecDifference += 86400 * 1000; // 86400 seconds in a day
  // And convert the milliseconds back to hours.
  document.getElementById("Output").value = (msecDifference / 1000 / 60 / 60);
}


// Plumbing to make the example interactive.
document.body.addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
  recalculate();
});
recalculate();
```

```html
From
<input id="Time1" value="10:00">to
<input id="Time2" value="8:30">
<hr>Hours:
<input id="Output" readonly>
```

Comment: please put the link to jsfiddle

Comment: Here's the JSFiddle link, I've modified it a little for it to work.. https://jsfiddle.net/SphinX/jszLa3dx/

Comment: What happens if I enter "10:30" in the first box and "11:11" in the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the javascript [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object to convert the 2 inputs to a date, then calculate the difference in milliseconds.
From there, you can easily convert the number of milliseconds back to a string in the `hh:mm` format.

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/194/) or code below, comments are in the code explaining each step.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/194/

---

**HTML**

```
<input class="Time1" value="10:00" />
<input class="Time2" value="10:30" />
<input class="Hours" value="0" />
<hr>
<button class="calc">Calculate</button>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".Time1, .Time2").change(calculate);
   $('.calc').click(calculate);
   calculate();
 });

 function calculate() {
   var d1,
     d2,
     t1 = $('.Time1').val().split(/\:/g),
     t2 = $('.Time2').val().split(/\:/g),
     diff = 0,
     hh = '',
     mm = '';

    d1 = new Date(); // Create date object
    d1.setHours(t1[0]); // Set the hours to match time 1
  d1.setMinutes(t1[1]); // And the minutes
  d2 = new Date(d1.getTime()); // Duplicate the first Date ...
  d2.setHours(t2[0]); // ... and update it's hours to match Time 2 ...
  d2.setMinutes(t2[1]); // ... and it's minutes

  var diff = d2 - d1; // Subtract d1 from d2 to calulcate the difference in ms
  diff += (diff < 0) ? 86400 * 1000 : 0; // d2 is on next day

  // Format difference to hh:mm
  var hh = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  hh = (hh.toString().length === 1) ? '0' + hh : hh; // Add leading '0' if needed
  var mm = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  mm = (mm.toString().length === 1) ? '0' + mm : mm; // Add leading '0' if needed

    // Set the difference in the appropriate input
  $('.Hours').val(hh + ':' + mm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Date object and floating point calculations for this, because you can end up with results like `1.183333` etc. Here's a small "library" that only uses integers and gives exact results:

```js
function parse(time) {
    var r = time.toLowerCase().match(/^(\d+)(:(\d+))?\s*([ap])\.?m/);

    if (r) {
        return {
            h: Number(r[1]) + (r[4] == 'p' ? 12 : 0),
            m: Number(r[3]) || 0
        };
    }

    r = time.split(':');
    return {
        h: Number(r[0]),
        m: Number(r[1]) || 0
    }
}

function delta(t1, t2) {
    var a = parse(t1),
        b = parse(t2);

    return {
        h: b.h - a.h + 24 * (a.h > b.h) - 1 * (a.m > b.m),
        m: b.m - a.m + 60 * (a.m > b.m)
    }
}

function format(p) {
    return [
        p.h < 10 ? '0' : '',
        p.h,
        ':',
        p.m < 10 ? '0' : '',
        p.m
    ].join('');
}

////////

a = '8:30 pm';
b = '03:27';

document.write(format(delta(a, b)));
```